# RestSharp not deserializing

Tags: json, restsharp

For some reason RestSharp is not deserializing the response:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseURL);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/location/" + locationID, Method.GET);
IRestResponse<Location> response = client.Execute<Location>(request);
return response.Data;
```

I confirm the Web API is returning valid result.
The `response` object has:

Content: {"LocationID":3,"PrintName":"MyCountry","ISO3166_1_alpha3":"XXX"}

StatusCode: OK

ResponseStatus: Completed

However `response.Data` has a Location object with default values (null).

Using Json.NET over RestSharp Content works (meaning the correct data is there):

```
Location loc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(response.Content);
```

The Location class should not matter in this case since Json.NET is able to deserialize. For some reason RestSharp is not deserializing.

```
public class Location
    {
        public int LocationID;
        public string PrintName;
        public string ISO3166_1_alpha3;
    }
```

Comment: Lets see your `Location` class.

Comment: @CrescentFresh it should not matter, since Json.NET is able to deserialize the same content. I think there is some problem with RestSharp. I'll include, anyway, it's simple.

Comment: what Content-Type header is being returned in the response?

Answer (score 3):

I think RestSharp client will only deserialize properties. Try to append

```
{ get; set; }
```

to each field. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the server is returning an incorrect Content-Type (not 'application/json'). If so, you can tell Restsharp to do json deserialization by setting the correct Content-Type:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseURL);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/location/" + locationID, Method.GET);

//because the response returned is probably an incorrect content type, fix it here
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

IRestResponse<Location> response = client.Execute<Location>(request);
return response.Data;
```